# How to prevent launching other application from my application

Tags: android

I want to write an application that can prevent some application from launching. My requirement is to block some application for some period. So what is the way to block or prevent others application from starting or launching through my application.

My question is --  Is it possible to prevent launching other application from my application? If yes then what is the way.

I tried killing the running application. But it only kills when the application is in the background. When the application is in opened state(displayed on the screen) the killing of the application is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what is the way to block or prevent others application from starting or launching through my application.

Write your own home screen, so you are the one doing the launching, and implement your launching rules there.

This will cover basic scenarios. It will not help with:

- Stopping apps that are launched via notifications (e.g., in response to an incoming SMS)
- Stopping apps that are launched via other things in the system bar on tablets (e.g., some tablets let you get to the Settings app from there)
- Stopping the user from rebooting their device in safe mode and getting rid of your home screen

The only way to handle those scenarios is to create your own ROM mod with adjustments to the operating system, then distribute that ROM mod (e.g., on your own devices).